# How to map CSV file headers to mysql table column (fields)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am importing CSV files with dynamic headers, e.g., sometimes the CSV file may have headers (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`) and sometimes (`f_name`, `name`, `Email_address`).

I want a view to show the mapping from uploaded CSV file headers to MySQL table columns. An example is in the picture below, in which CSV header `Fname` is mapped to a mysql table user column `internalKey`:

[image]

Is there any good gem to do this?

Comment: There isn't anything special about mapping a list of strings into another. You don't need a specific tool to do this. Perhaps there is none.

Comment: I agree with @sawa. Do you import a CSV direct to a table? maybe you can post your code and we can help you clarify where you hace to improve.